# How can i compare natural numbers in prolog?

Tags: numbers, prolog, compare

I have a function that takes two arguments and compares if they are natural numbers in their unit form and if the first arg is bigger than the second!

So here is the code I've written but every time it gets me "no".

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
sum(X,0,X) :- nat(X).
sum(X,s(Y),s(Z)) :- sum(X,Y,Z).
gr(X,Y) :- nat(s(X)), nat(s(Y)), X>Y.
```

What goes wrong? Everything is in Prolog . the function is the gr() .

Comment: Can you show what queries you've tried? Are you trying to do `gr(3,2)` for example? Or `gr(s(s(s(0))), s(s(0)))`?

Comment: i tried both of em but nothing !

Comment: Your code doesn't handle "normal" natural numbers. Any natural number has to be expressed as `s(s(...(s(0))...))` the way it's currently written. And prolog can't compare `s(s(s(0)))` with `s(s(0))` using `>/2`, so that will generate an error. Thus, in either case, `gr` won't work. Try changing `>` to `@>` and try `gr(s(s(s(0))), s(s(0))).`

Answer (score 2):

First, you probably want for `sum` rather this:

```
sum(0, Y, Y) :-
    nat(Y).
sum(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :-
    sum(X, Y, Z).
```

This is so that Prolog can recognize that the two clauses are exclusive by only looking at the first argument.

Now to your *greater than*:

```
% gr(X, Y) is true if X is greater than Y
gr(X, Y) :- sm(Y, X).
% sm(X, Y) is true if X is smaller than Y
sm(0, s(Y)) :-
    nat(Y).
sm(s(X), s(Y)) :-
    sm(X, Y).
```

To answer your actual question: what goes wrong is that the operator `>` works on integers (like 1 or 0 or -19), not on compound terms. The operator `@>` will work (see the documentation of the implementation you are using), but I have the feeling you might actually want to be explicit about it.